Why DOM has not script tag?
I'm developing SSR application, and have a problem. <script> tag added programaticaly is exisits only in a server response, but it is not instert into the DOM. The script appears in DOM only after page reload or on initial load. But it is not in the DOM  if user navigates to the page interacting with UI.
This is a service using in Page constructor.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ScriptService {
  private readonly platform = inject(PLATFORM_ID)
  private readonly document = inject(DOCUMENT)
  private readonly head = this.document.head

  public addScript(src: string): void {
    if (!this.isServer()) {
      return
    }

    const script = this.document.createElement('script')
    script.setAttribute('src', src)
    this.head.appendChild(script)
  }

  private isServer(): boolean {
    return isPlatformServer(this.platform)
  }
}

export class ExampleComponent {
  private readonly scriptService = inject(ScriptService)

  constructor() {
    this.scriptService.addScript('qweqwe')
  }
}

If I delete the section that checks, is the action happens on the server, everything works fine. But I don't understand why should delete it? Why should I insert the script on the client side if I can add it to the DOM on the server side?
Thank you!

Navigating between pages likely means, that newly fetched content gets inserted on the client side via innerHTML - which doesn't execute script elements. Therefor the explicit creating & appending of a script element using DOM methods, on the client side, is necessary in that instance. But with your if condition that checks if this is running on the server side, that part doesn't happen then.

@C3roe I thought what every time user navigates in SSR application the server sends whole html page related to browser URL. And before hydration end user just see the html received from the server. Is it not right?

@Raji issue not reproducible stackblitz -> cd test -> npm i -> npm run start
